# react-native-maps no me funciona en Android

Tags: android, react-native

Estoy intentando usar react-native-maps (https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps) en un dispositivo Android compilando el ejemplo pero la aplicación se cierra cuando selecciono un ejemplo, debido supongo a que no consigue acceder correctamente a los mapas de Google. Si lo intento desde el emulador no se muestra el mapa, ya que no tiene instalado los servicios de Google, pero no se cierra. He probado a usar mi `API KEY` y tampoco funciona. Lo estoy probando desde la versión 5.1.1.

Comment: Hola Carlos, agrega el mensaje de error desplegado en el LogCat por favor, es importante para saber cual es el problema.

Comment: Estuve probando pero no me devolvía nada. En cuanto pueda lo pruebo de nuevo y si consigo que me salga el error lo añado.

Comment: Es importante que habilites la API KEY para que pruebes el Mapa también.

Comment: ¿En que sentido dices que la habilite? La API KEY la cree para Maps de Android. Si hago 'run-android' la aplicación no se cierra pero tampoco muestra nada, si la compilo con 'gradlew assembleRelease' se me cierra pero tampoco muestra error con el logcat porque quízas así no permite la depuración.

Answer (score 2):

Hola debes crear la llave API KEY y luego registrarla en el console google
para crear la llave debes ingresar desde la consola  a la siguiente ruta
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin

y luego ejecutar

```
keytool -genkey -v -keyalg RSA -sigalg SHA1withRSA -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -dname "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=CO"
```

desbes validar que el archivo "%USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore" no exista en esa ruta

luego ejecutar

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Copiar la llave SHA1 y pegarlo en el console de google

y seguir las instrucciones de react-native-maps para la instalación

https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md

Saludos espero que esto te sirva.

Comment: Gracias pero realmente ya conseguí echarlo andar. Se me arreglo con el tiempo cuando actualizaron a la 0.6